# How to remove items from a Mongodb collection based on the lack of a specific key?

Tags: mongodb-query

As the title says, I'm trying to remove items from a collection based on the lack of a specific key.
Is there a nice way to do this?

For example, in the set below, I want to delete all records that DO NOT have an `"updated"` key, such as the 2nd item which only has a `"created"` key but not a `"updated"` key:

```
{
  "_id": {"$oid":"63fdd6becfa52a984f0a0e3a"},
  "name": "Foo",
  "created": {"$date":{"$numberLong":"1677579966215"}},
  "updated": {"$date":{"$numberLong":"1677579966547"}},
},
{
  "_id": {"$oid":"63fdd778cfa52a984f0a0e3b"},
  "name": "Bar",
  "created": {"$date":{"$numberLong":"1677580152867"}},
},

...

{
  "_id": {"$oid":"63fdd785cfa52a984f0a0e3e"},
  "name": "Baz",
  "created": {"$date":{"$numberLong":"1677580165073"}},
  "updated": {"$date":{"$numberLong":"1677580165754"}},
}
```

Is there a nice way to achieve this or do I have to do it one record at a time by using `find()` to extract the entire collection and then manually loop through each record one by one and apply `deleteOne()` to each matching record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `remove` function with `$exists`, like this:

```
db.collection.remove({
  updated: {
    $exists: false
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Although I had to use `delete_many()` instead of `remove()` but that's probably specific to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Use deleteMany() and a filter that checks if "updated" is not null.

Use:

```
db.yourcollection.deleteMany(

  { "updated": {$ne:null} }
  
);
```